# LASSO Regression not Improving with Shrinkage Increase

Tags: regression, lasso, linear, glmnet

I am trying to reproduce a figure (3.7) from the ESL Book using the dataset for prostate cancer [https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/datasets/prostate.data](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/ElemStatLearn/datasets/prostate.data)

The figure essentially shows how the error of prediction for the LSPA using LASSO Regression decreases as we increase the shrinkage factor lambda (from 0 to 1 by 0.1 steps).
[image]

It says in the book they obtained this by scaling the dataset and performing cross validation to determine the errors.

I want to do that, but I dont want to do CV. I simply want to use one training and one testing chunk for every lambda.

I wrote the following code:

```
set.seed(1632)
library(glmnet)
#read prostate data
data = read.csv("prostate.txt", header = TRUE, sep=",")
head(data)
#remove row number column
data = data[2:ncol(data)]
#split into test and train
train = data[data$train==TRUE,]
test = data[data$train==FALSE,]
#remove train test indicator
train = train[1:ncol(train)-1]
test = test[1:ncol(test)-1]
#split into X and Y
trainX = as.matrix(train[1:ncol(train)-1])
trainY = as.matrix(train[ncol(train)])
testX = as.matrix(test[1:ncol(test)-1])
testY = as.matrix(test[ncol(test)])
#scale indicators
trainX = scale(trainX)
testX = scale(testX)
#LASSO Regression Model
lambdas = seq(0,1,0.1)
lasso_scores = rep(0,11)
i = 1
for (ld in lambdas){
  lasso_model = glmnet(trainX,trainY,lambda = ld)
  lasso_scores[i] = mean(abs(predict(lasso_model,testX)-testY))
  i = i +1
}
plot(lambdas,lasso_scores)
```

This code produces the following:
[image]

The result is contradictory to what the book says; the error is increasing as lambda increases. I have no idea where I went wrong. But when I use the cv.glmnet function, the problem seems to go away and I get the following:

```
c = data[1:ncol(data)-1]
lasso = cv.glmnet(as.matrix(c[1:ncol(c)-1]),as.matrix(c[ncol(c)-1]), lambda=lambdas)
plot(lambdas,lasso$cvm)
```

[image]

But I don't want to do it that way; I don't want to use the cv.glmnet function, but want to use one test and one train set.

Comment: The curve that you create looks the same as the curve in the book. It is just that the error is different for zero versus full shrinking. That depends on the situation.

Comment: the one I created with CV, yes. But the one I created with one test and one train set is the opposite of the one in the book.